# How to merge elements of a GridView

Tags: android, performance, gridview, tablelayout

i'm implementing a activity where the user can see images from different sizes and proportions on a GridView. I don't want to modify this images proportions.

Is it possible with GridViews or my best option is to build a TableLayout and just add each image to a TableRow?

---

Example: If it loads a 3x4 image, i want it to scale to satify some width and height constraint  and them merge the necessary GridView's elements to keep the 3x4 proportion rate.

My objective is to reach something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6jmt2x5ly1k2p92/grid.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can as a custom gridview, I haven't tested my own, and too low to comment. So on this [link](http://android-vogue.blogspot.ca/2011/06/custom-gridview-in-android-with.html) you will find an image on the bottom using a gridview notice that the last item is larger that the rest and the middle left item is also off scaled.